# Materialize CSS - Select does not have name nor proper value in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm having trouble understanding how materialize CSS `<select>` tag works.

In regular HTML select tags, you'd insert a `name=""` attribute, and for each option, a `value=""` attribute, which seem to be missing in materialize CSS.

This code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

renders into this in DOM:

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
  <div class="select-wrapper"><span class="caret">▼</span>
    <input class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-273ec07d-e7c4-e689-e2e3-6a57ff2f6293" value="Choose your option" type="text">
    <ul style="width: 296px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;" id="select-options-273ec07d-e7c4-e689-e2e3-6a57ff2f6293" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown">
      <li class="disabled"><span>Choose your option</span></li><li class="active selected"><span>Option 1</span></li><li class=""><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class=""><span>Option 3</span></li>
    </ul>
    <select class="initialized">
          <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

Problems I am having:

1. Where and how do I set the name for that select element (to be represented accordingly in the rendered `input` element)?
2. The values are the texts being displayed in the list. I wish to have different values than the display strings, e.g:

`<option value="1">regular style</option>
<option value="2">bold style</option>
<option value="3">italic style</option>`

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: Generally-speaking the way these `<select>` replacements work is that you apply the name as normal (`<select name="foo">`) and the JavaScript handles all the labor of re-formatting the `<select>` into something 'pretty'.  Have you tried simply following standard HTML approach to see if Materialize renders it correctly?

Comment: @RobertC It seem so trivial, I was positive I have tested that, but I must have made something wrong. You are correct, simply adding `name="foo"` solves it. it doesn't render into the DOM as I would have expected, nevertheless, it works. Make an answer out of it, and I'll mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialize handles `<select>` replacement like most other libraries; follow standard HTML conventions like `name="foo"` or `<option value="A">But I'm showing other text here</option>`.

The output will take these into consideration when creating the prettier, functional form.

**Note**: The Materialize CSS documentation does show the `<select>` tag without most of the common elements (like `name=""`), but I think this is more to present the cleanest, most minimal code possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you an example to add name to a materialize css select

If your html indicates this

```
<div class="col s3">
    <span class="required"></span>
    <select id="piezas" name="piezas" class="validate">
        <option value="-1" disabled selected>Elija Pieza</option>
        <option value="1">Tornillo</option>
        <option value="2">Clavo</option>
        <option value="3">Cable</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Your select will be transformed and shown in the dom to something like this

```
<div class="col s3">
    <span class="required"></span>
    <div class="select-wrapper valid">
        
        <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-9e9993fe-936f-86eb-22f5-ec638cf0121d" name="piezas-materialize" aria-invalid="false">
        
        <ul id="select-options-9e9993fe-936f-86eb-22f5-ec638cf0121d" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0">
            <li class="disabled selected" id="select-options-9e9993fe-936f-86eb-22f5-ec638cf0121d0" tabindex="0">
                <span>Elija Pieza</span>
            </li>
            <li id="select-options-9e9993fe-936f-86eb-22f5-ec638cf0121d1" tabindex="0">
                <span>Tornillo</span>
            </li>
            <li id="select-options-9e9993fe-936f-86eb-22f5-ec638cf0121d2" tabindex="0">
                <span>Clavo</span></li>
            <li id="select-options-9e9993fe-936f-86eb-22f5-ec638cf0121d3" tabindex="0">
                <span>Cable</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
        </svg>

        <select id="piezas" name="piezas" class="validate ignore" tabindex="-1">
            <option value="-1" disabled="" selected="">Elija Pieza</option>
            <option value="1">Tornillo</option>
            <option value="2">Clavo</option>
            <option value="3">Cable</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

To add name to this selects, use the following JavaScript code to iterate all of them and add a custom name.
Bare in mind that you need to add a sufix to the name to avoid same name on many selects

```
    let allSelects = $('.select-dropdown.dropdown-trigger');    
    for (i = 0; i < allSelects .length; i++) {
        let item = $(allSelects[i]);
        let name= item.parent().children()[3].name;
        item.attr("name", name + '-materialize');  // change -materialize for the sufix you like  
    }
```